# when write " npm install " command on cmd then display error

Tags: laravel

when write `npm install` command on cmd then display error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Pradeep.ITV>cd blog

C:\Users\Pradeep.ITV\blog>php artisan make:auth
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully.

C:\Users\Pradeep.ITV\blog>npm install
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\NODEJS\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-12T07_25_03_933Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Pradeep.ITV\blog>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error Usually appears when your node and npm versions are older. Try to upgrade it to at least  node 7.3.0 and npm 4.1. Then Try `npm install` again.

Comment: but my node is  10.16.0 and npm is 6.9.0  and im  not  able to execute npm install  command  what should i do